# Main column figure width in tint/tufte package

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tint, tufte

I have the following `Rmd` file that uses the `tint` package based on the `tufte` package:

````
---
title: "Test title"
author: ""
date: ""
output: 
  tint::tintPdf
classoption: twoside
---


```{r one, echo=FALSE, fig.width=8}
plot(pressure)
```


```{r two, echo=FALSE, fig.width=4}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I would expect the second figure to be half as wide as the first, but it appears that both are the width of the main column and that I'm really just altering the aspect ratio by specifying `fig.width`.

[image]

Is it possible to have a figure that is narrower than the width of the main column when using `tint`/`tufte`?

PS `pressure` is from the `datasets` package.

---

### Edit

I could fake it like this:

````
```{r two, echo=FALSE, fig.width=4}
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(pressure)
```
````

but is there a less cludgy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the `out.width` chunk option.  This needs to be a character value which will be inserted into the LaTeX as a width, not just a number like `fig.width`.  For example, changing your second chunk to

````
```{r two, echo=FALSE, out.width="2in"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

produces this output:

[image]